Im looking for papers to read to strengthen my understanding of overall cs theory
I took automata theory and the things we learn in that class interest me a lot and am looking to read more papers to take a deeper dive into cs theory if any of y'all have any paper suggestions that would be awesome!

CS Theory is a (conceptually) big field. Do you want more papers going deeper into automata theory, or other parts of CS Theory as well? You might look at e.g. the table of contents of books such as Arora-Barak, Sipser, Wigderson, Moore-Mertens and see if anything catches your eye, to help clarify what kinds of topics you are looking for in this question.

Read Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest and Stein and
Practical Foundations for Programming Languages by Robert Harper. If you prefer the first one, you're "Theory A", and if the second then you're "Theory B".

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
